# repent & seeking forgiveness after cumming out during fast in ramadan

Tags: fiqh, sawm, tawba

if a teenager failed to control his hormones and sexual organs and he just ejaculated during fast in Ramadan what can he do to repent for his deed immediately and to seek ALLAH'S forgiveness as quick as possible so that he can fast till iftari without any guilt or stress on his mind baring in mind that in his social area there are no poor people so he cannot feed 60 poor people , neither is there a slave , and what are the chances that he will be able to fast for 60 days when he could not even fast for a day

also if a housewife at your home is working non-stop all day and she feels tired and she desperately needs a rest does freeing her from household chores for a period of time class as freeing a slave

Answer (score 1):

Masturbation does not require kaffarah. Kaffarah is required because of sexual intercourse and not the emission of semen.

Thus, a man who had vaginal or anal intercourse, whether they ejaculate sperm or not, would have do to kaffarah, and so would the woman who participated.

As for masturbation, if it leads to sperm coming out, then the fast is broken and a major sin has been committed. You should repent sincerely to Allah, promise never to do it again, and keep qadhaa fasts for each one you have broken.

Finally, if someone did have to give kaffarah, he could pay an online charity and they would feed the 60 people on his behalf.